# Deploy multiple Rails Apps on Linode with niginx and passanger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, linode

I have two rails app on my local server with two different databases. Both app are using Ruby 1.9.1 and Rails 3.2.13. Currently, I have one of the two application up and running on linode.

I followed this tutorial to install first app:

https://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-nginx/ubuntu-10.04-lucid

So, my app is running on passenger with nginx.

I wanted to add this other app.

My first app is on directory:

```
/var/www/abc
```

Can any one tell me process of how to upload second app? What changes need to be done on Linode to deploy second app?

Comment: Could you add more details? Did you upload the first app? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you mean running two rails app in Nginx? Nginx supports virtual server and you can set up another server configuration.

Comment: @HenryFinucane I have added the link i followed. My app is up and running properly on linode. This app i uploaded long back. Now, I have new app which i wanted to upload. But not getting how to o it.

Comment: You'll need to adjust which port passenger runs on locally, then point the virtual server in the nginx.conf to that port.